# Replacement for celery with equivalent nutrients?

Tags: substitutions, nutrient-composition

I have this recipe:

- 2 celery sticks
- 1 cucumber (large)
- 2 large handfuls of spinach leaves
- 1 large handful of lettuce (dark)
- 1/2 freshly squeezed lemon

But I don't like the "aroma" of celery. So what can I use in place of the celery sticks? The replacement should have similar nutritional values to celery.

The best replacement I have come up with is 2 tomatoes.

Comment: Celery has nutrition?  I thought it was just crunchy water, like lettuce.

Comment: Any green veg is going to be a fair replacement. If you are after maximum nutritional intake and not fashion, you need to chew them, not drink them. Saliva and chewing are major parts of digestive process

Comment: @Joe: Dang you for beating me to that comment!

Comment: I suspect that celery is included in this recipe as a flavouring rather than for it's nutritional value. Simply remove or reduce the celery and increase the other items.

Comment: I don't know if this is myth or not, but I-think-I-heard-it-from-a-guy-but-also-may-have-dreamt that celery (like iceberg lettuce) requires more calories to burn than is contained therein; hence making it a net loss in terms of caloric intake (so in addition to flavor, it may be there as a weight loss thing).

Comment: @mfg : those calculations typically include the energy required to chew ... if this is a drink, it's likely gone through a blender, so wouldn't hold true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iceberg Lettuce, as it is also very low in vitamins and minerals like celery and has a good crunch.  According to the USDA's "MyPlate", 1 cup of iceberg is 1/2 serving vegetables, and 1 stalk of celery is 1/2 serving vegetables, so to get equivalent nutritional value for 2 stalks would take 2 cups shredded.

You could add more vitamins and minerals by replacing the celery with something more nutrient dense.

Comment: They indeed have very similar (lack of) nutrition: [iceberg lettuce](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/vegetables-and-vegetable-products/2476/2) and [celery](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/vegetables-and-vegetable-products/2396/2) on nutritiondata.self.com. (Choose 100 grams from the drop-down for easier comparison.)